# In Swift what does it mean if a type is bracketed, eg. "(String)"

Tags: swift

Simple question, difficult to Google and don't remember seeing this in the documentation. Code below shows the variable as "(String)" as opposed to just "String"  What does that mean?

```
var myDictionary = [String:Bool]()
// put whatever data you want in there, for example
myDictionary["cat"] = true
var firstKey = [String](myDictionary.keys)[0] //firstKey is type (String) as opposed to "String"
var myString = "this is my string" // has type String
var myOptionalString: String?  // has type String?
var myUninitializedString: String!  // has type String!
```

I guess it may have something to do with inferring the type?

Screenshot (from code completion window, a quick way to check the type): [image: screenshot of (String)]

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. If your screenshot is from Xcode's variables window, all the types are in parentheses, and there's no difference for me between the type display of `firstKey` and the type display of `myString`. (A full code example might help—the fragment you've posted would, of course, throw a runtime error when setting `firstKey` as there aren't any elements in `myDictionary`...)

Comment: To repro: var myString = "this is my string" as (String), then check the type

Comment: @MirekE How does that reproduce the issue, exactly? I see no difference in `myString` in the variables window between `var myString = "this is my string"` and `var myString = "this is my string" as (String)`. Are we looking at a different window? A different version of Xcode, maybe? I'm on 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Comment: The screenshot is from the code completion menu.

Comment: @shim You might want to edit that into the question, and tell us what you're trying to complete, exactly, when it pops up...

Comment: Nothing, it's just a convenient place to check the type.

Comment: @Matt - I am on 6.2 (6C107a) and check the type by Option-clicking on the variable name. xxx as String shows String, xxx as (String) shows (String)

Comment: @shim - btw, you might want to edit your post on the myOptionalString line, it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, still not sure what you're talking about

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Interestingly, if you take the first key in a more standard fashion, i.e. `var firstKey = myDictionary.keys.first!` (which will just grab the first value from the iterator, rather than creating an array) then you get `String` rather than `(String)`... I can also reproduce it with `var array = [String](["test"]); var firstKey = array[0]`

Comment: Single element tuple?

Comment: @MirekE Yeah, could be. Maybe the completion's getting confused. It doesn't seem to be actually creating a single element tuple, but maybe the parens and complexity of the expression are confusing Xcode.

Comment: Seems like the most plausible explanation, but how does [String]() create an array of tuples?

Comment: It is a single element tuple, because in the example you can do `firstKey.0`.

Comment: @vacawama In the example you can do `myString.0`, too :D

Comment: It does seem to be confusing XCode, because when you put this in there it stops recognizing other brackets.     btw getting the first key using .first! is a much better way to go about it, thanks.

Comment: Also fyi this way of getting the keys is directly from Apple's documentation http://imgur.com/CHngybR   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107

Comment: @Matt and the op - it could be confusion from the [String] (xxx)[0]. If I rewrite it to Array<String>(myDictionary.keys)[0], it reports that the type is String.

Comment: If you do let `allKeys = [String](myDictionary.keys]` and then `for key in allKeys`  `key` is of type `String` not `(String)`, but it shows `allKeys` as of type `[(String)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means it's a single-element tuple, which acts exactly the same as a non-tuple of that same type. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I wouldn't, but it messes up XCode's detection of closing brackets.

Comment: Try giving it explicit type: `let firstKey: String = ...`